# Alfresco Explorer giving error after upgrade from 3.4.d (community) to 4.0.d(community)

Tags: java, alfresco, jboss5.x

I upgraded from Alfresco 3.4.d (community) to Alfresco 4.0.d (community). The upgrade process didn't show any errors.

The CIFS access and all the APIs, webscripts etc work fine. Also the Share app works. But when I try to access the /alfresco web app (Explorer) I get the error:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException - org.apache.opencmis.browser.BrowseServlet from BaseClassLoader

I found out that this class is present in the previous version (3.4.d) in the opencmis-test-browser library. This lib doesn't exist in the 4.0.d version.

Can anyone help me with that? Why am I getting this error? Any idea how to fix it?

Stacktrace:

```
2015-03-04 11:40:10,290 INFO  [STDOUT] 11:40:10,288  ERROR [shared_impl.util.ClassUtils] Class org.apache.opencmis.browser.BrowseServlet not found
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.opencmis.browser.BrowseServlet from BaseClassLoader@7b888da5{vfszip:/opt/jboss-eap-5.1/server/default/deploy/alfresco.war/}
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:477)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
        at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.ClassUtils.classForName(ClassUtils.java:139)
        at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.ClassUtils.simpleClassForName(ClassUtils.java:158)
        at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.webapp.webxml.WebXml.getFacesServletMappings(WebXml.java:129)
        at org.apache.myfaces.application.jsp.JspViewHandlerImpl.getServletMapping(JspViewHandlerImpl.java:381)
        at org.apache.myfaces.application.jsp.JspViewHandlerImpl.renderView(JspViewHandlerImpl.java:222)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:146)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:147)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.filter.beans.NullFilter.doFilter(NullFilter.java:68)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor790.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory.java:103)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy458.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.filter.beans.BeanProxyFilter.doFilter(BeanProxyFilter.java:82)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.alfresco.repo.webdav.auth.BaseSSOAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BaseSSOAuthenticationFilter.java:136)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor790.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory.java:103)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy458.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.filter.beans.BeanProxyFilter.doFilter(BeanProxyFilter.java:82)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:58)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:183)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:95)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:451)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2015-03-04 11:40:10,293 INFO  [STDOUT] 11:40:10,292  ERROR [faces.webapp._ErrorPageWriter] An exception occurred
javax.faces.FacesException
        at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.ClassUtils.simpleClassForName(ClassUtils.java:163)
        at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.webapp.webxml.WebXml.getFacesServletMappings(WebXml.java:129)
        at org.apache.myfaces.application.jsp.JspViewHandlerImpl.getServletMapping(JspViewHandlerImpl.java:381)
        at org.apache.myfaces.application.jsp.JspViewHandlerImpl.renderView(JspViewHandlerImpl.java:222)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:146)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:147)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.filter.beans.NullFilter.doFilter(NullFilter.java:68)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor790.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory.java:103)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy458.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.filter.beans.BeanProxyFilter.doFilter(BeanProxyFilter.java:82)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.alfresco.repo.webdav.auth.BaseSSOAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BaseSSOAuthenticationFilter.java:136)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor790.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory.java:103)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy458.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.filter.beans.BeanProxyFilter.doFilter(BeanProxyFilter.java:82)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:58)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:183)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:95)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:451)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.opencmis.browser.BrowseServlet from BaseClassLoader@7b888da5{vfszip:/opt/jboss-eap-5.1/server/default/deploy/alfresco.war/}
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:477)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
        at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.ClassUtils.classForName(ClassUtils.java:139)
        at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.ClassUtils.simpleClassForName(ClassUtils.java:158)
        ... 51 more
```

Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem - the class package has changed in 4.0.d.
It has changed from org.apache.opencmis.browser.BrowseServlet to org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.browser.BrowseServlet

Changing this in the web.xml has resolved the problem.